# How to escape double quotes in JSON using Java

Tags: java, json

What is the best way to handle double quotes that exist inside a JSON String ? I get the string from an external source.
Escaping the double quotes would escape all the double quotes, even the ones that wrap around the key and the value. I would ideally just want a way to escape the quotes inside the value. In the example below, the string "quotes" breaks the JSON. 
What would be the best way to handle this ?
Appreciate your input. Thanks!

```
@Test
public void isValidJSON()
{
    String testJSONString = "{\"messageType\":\"typeA\", \"subject\":\"Here is a subject with \"quotes\" in it\" }";        
    try
    {
        new JSONObject(testJSONString);
    } catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The error I get is:

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 60 [character 61 line 1]
```

Comment: Double escaping them should work `\\\"` although you should rarely hand write JSON strings like that. For example - the JSON object `{"Name":"Hello \"World\""}` becomes `"{\"Name\":\" Hello \\\"World\\\"\" }"`

Comment: As you expected, you get an error.  The code you posted doesn't really help us; what does the original string look like?  If you haven't wrapped it in JSON yet, escape the original string, and *then* put it into the JSON wrapper.

Comment: The error here has nothing to do with quotes, you left the closing brace off the end.

Comment: The missing brace was my typo. Edited the post with the correction.

Comment: I dont build the JSON String above. I get it from an external source. I have to build the JSON Object from the String that I get from the external source. When one of the string values contains quotes in them, it breaks the JSON object instantiation. I might not be the first person encountering this, and so wanted to reach out to know if there is a way to get around this.

Comment: Escape all quotes in the string values first, *before* JSONifying it.  No need to escape your own quotes.  I don't really understand why you're finding this difficult; its all a matter of doing things in the correct order.  You still haven't shown us what the original string looks like.

Comment: are you building the json string yourself?  if so, then that's your issue.  don't do that.  use a json library to build the json string.

Comment: @user2475664 : did you solved this issue?